# Resources for parallel/multiprocessor audio processing

Tags: multithreading, audio, multiprocessing

I've been spending quite some time lately learning the specifics of real-time audio processing and most of the libraries/tools I've found are in the form of c/c++ code or scripting/graphical languages with compiled c/c++ code under the hood.

Using callback based APIs, it's pretty simple to run the audio process apart from the GUI or other processes in an App. But, something I haven't been able to find is how to use multiple processes/threads for the audio processing part of an application.

Can you please provide links, book titles, whatever that can be relevant?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do multi-threaded DSP for audio. This isn't really done much because high performance audio requires low latency and real-time scheduling. To do multi-threaded DSP,  you would need to pass data between threads, which usually involves mutexes. It's very difficult to get real-time programming to work when using mutexes.

Of course there are alternatives to mutexes, and there exist plenty of non-blocking datastructures, but, at the end of the day, parallelizing your audio DSP algorithms lends less of a performance gain than other forms of parallelism.

If, instead, you are interested in getting audio data in and out of your callback, you will need to learn a bit about non-blocking data structures. You might want to look at the source code for PortAudio. In particular the RingBuffer in PortAudio is a portable, non-blocking data-passing structure which is useful for many applications in getting data between threads without blocking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bjorn. I'm aware of lock-free structures and how to get data to/from the audio callback. What I'm talking about is using parallelism within the audio callback. Suppose you're writing a plugin host, a modular/patch system such as PD or you have a massively complicated algorithm that you want to run as a plugin. You'll need to fork off processing within the callback, collect the results and somehow aggregate them to produce the audio output. My answer is: What are the techniques for doing this sort of parallel audio processing?

Comment: I don't think much, if anything, is written about this because it's highly application dependent.

Comment: I meant to say: "My question is..."